# Getting SqlException, Timeout error

Tags: sql, wpf, sql-server, database

I'm making a WPF application that is data driven and uses dynamic data. Now through the development process on my local computer, everything went fine, the application and my local sql server were functioning perfect.

Now what I did was transfer my database from my local machine to my server, By copying and pasting the database into the SqlServer DATA Folder on my remote server.
Now I'm able to connect to the server just fine, and i made sure to test the connection strings in Visual Studio to make sure it connects, and when i click "Test Connection" it says that the connection was successful.

But now when I try run the application, using the database that is located remotely, I get error:

> Sql Exception, Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

And I find it strange because it was working fine 10 minutes ago on my local machine, so  I think it must be a setting I have on my remote server or something?

Also I'm using LINQ to SQL, and I've even tried editing the LINQ to SQL Classes (dbml file) and increasing the timeout and such but still get the exact same error. I dont get what I'm doing wrong. Because the whole thing was working not too long ago on my local machine...

Any ideas what the problem is or how I could fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Do you get that error a few minutes after you start your application or the moment you start it?

Comment: can you debug and see exactly which line is causing the issue? maybe post your connection string

Comment: This is probably a problem in the app layer.  When you connect to a database, you often provide a default timeout for queries.  Try running a simpler query on the connection.  Can you post the connection statement?

Comment: Trace the SQL command with Profiler and see if the SQL being executed IS taking over the timeout (normally 15 seconds). If it is, pull the SQL from the profiler and try executing it in SSMS and see if it a) runs, or b) timesout. If it runs and doesn't out, I'd hazard a guess that perhaps the command you're calling calls something else on another PC which the remote SQL box doesn't have access to.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your reply. I am getting the error some seconds after I have started it. And everything command that tries to connect to the db is getting the error, Also i clicked the view detail, and under error I get this: {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection}   And also my connectionstring is this: Data Source=MyServerIP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=database;User ID=myadmin;Password=mypassword

Comment: Are you sure you tested the same connection that you have in the application?  Did you delete and recreate the ID myadmin on the remote database?   On a copy myadmin will have the same name but not the correct internal id.  Put the open in a try catch block to see that error.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. Yes i deleted and recreated the login id, quite a few times in fact... Could that also be a contribute? Also I have tried using the try and catch block. It is able to atleast get my program to run, but displays no data whatsoever.

Comment: In catch block display the error message  Catch(Exception Ex)  { Debug.WriteLine(Ex.msg);

Comment: Hi there, I have already tried putting the code in the try block, and then catch block i put:             catch(Exception Ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
            }                  But it still doesnt show any error messages, it just doesnt do the queries

Comment: Wrong.  If there is no errror then it performed the query and returned zero rows.

Comment: Hi, yeah it did display an error, I ment it didnt display any difference, I still got the same timeout error and in themessage field i got: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'ApplicationProject.Test' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.  Still have no idea why Its not working, Ive tried everything and still cant get it to work

Comment: Please show the try catch block.  That is not even a SQL like error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is generally due to Connection problem between server and the client. There may be a problem in network. Make Sure that database server is accessible from Application machine and no Firewalls are blocking the Connection.